# How to get defined thread status message and prevent using big heap memory?

Tags: java

I have many thread running at a time with different name. Like...
t_213, t_102, t_233 etc

Each thread execute a long process. I store the current status of that processes in a Map like.. 
`static final Map<String, String> messageMap = new HashMap<>(0);`. **I used Thread names as map Key.**

I monitor the status messages using Ajax **at a time** (From the messageMap by thread name)
Thread Class:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{
    public static Map<String, String> messageMap = new HashMap<>(0);

    private String threadName;

    public MyThread(String threadName){
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        messageMap.put(threadName, "Started process.");
        try{
            messageMap.put(threadName, "Processing....stage 1");
            //Long Process
            messageMap.put(threadName, "Processing....stage 2");

            messageMap.put(threadName, "Processing....stage 3");

            messageMap.put(threadName, "Process finished.");

        }catch(Exception e){
            messageMap.put(threadName, "Exception ."+e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    static String getMessage(String threadName){
        return messageMap.get(threadName)
    }
}
```

Monitor Class:

```
public MonitorClass extends DispatchAction {

    public ActionForward monitor(....httpRequest.....){
        String threadName = httpRequest.getParameter("threadName"); // t_213, t_102, t_233 etc
        String message = MyThread.getMessage(threadName);

        String json = gson.toJson(message);
        out.println(json);
        out.flush();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**The problem is. This takes a big heap memory.**
 Is this for memory leak ? or anything else. And how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: How big? How much memory should it take? How much would it take if you only had to store all the thread names with all the status messages? Is it more than twice that amount? Where is the most memory used? If memory is such a big issue, replace the status message by an int. That way you use only 4 bytes instead of 22.

Comment: For a single Thread: If I use 'statusMap' takes 200 Mb (Sometime 240 Mb), no use of 'statusMap' it takes around 75 Mb. For a thread the old message is replace by new (because i use threadName as key).